# Python Gymnasium Render being forced

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym, q-learning

I'm new to gym and I tried to do a simple qlearning programm but for some *(weird)* reason it won't let me get rid of the rendering part (which is taking forever)...

Here is my programm:

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode="human")

LEARNING_RATE = 0.1
DISCOUNT = 0.95
EPISODES = 25000

SHOW_EVERY = 500

DISCRETE_OS_SIZE = [20] * len(env.observation_space.low)
discrete_os_win_size = (env.observation_space.high - env.observation_space.low) / DISCRETE_OS_SIZE

q_table = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=0, size=(DISCRETE_OS_SIZE + [env.action_space.n]))


def get_discrete_state(state):
    discrete_state = (state - env.observation_space.low) / discrete_os_win_size
    return tuple(discrete_state.astype(int))


for episode in range(EPISODES):
    if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
        render = True
    else:
        render = False
    
    print("Episode:", episode)
    
    discrete_state = get_discrete_state(tuple(env.reset()[0].astype(int)))
    
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = np.argmax(q_table[discrete_state])
        new_state, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action)
        done = truncated or terminated
        
        new_discrete_state = get_discrete_state(new_state)
        
        # Rendering the episode
        # (Even removing this part does not help)
        if render:
            env.render()

        if not done:
            # Updating the Q-table
            max_future_q = np.max(q_table[new_discrete_state])
            current_q = q_table[discrete_state + (action, )]
            new_q = (1-LEARNING_RATE)* current_q + LEARNING_RATE * (reward + DISCOUNT * max_future_q)
            
            q_table[discrete_state + (action, )] = new_q
       
        # If the car made it to the goal
        elif new_state[0] >= env.unwrapped.goal_position:
            q_table[discrete_state + (action, )] = 0
            print("MADE IT ON EPISODE:", episode)
        discrete_state = new_discrete_state
    
env.close()
```

I tried:

- removing the `env.render()` part: did not work
- removing the `discrete_state` at the start and replace it by the default value `(13, 10)` by hand: kinda worked (episodes not rendering but also not the ones when `render` is True)

Answer (score 0):

In [Gymnasium Documentation](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.render), it says:

> By convention, if the render_mode is:
>
> - “human”: The environment is continuously rendered in the current display or terminal, usually for human consumption. **This rendering should occur during `step()` and `render()` doesn’t need to be called.** Returns None.

As long as you set the `render_mode` as `'human'`, it is inevitable to be rendered every step.